# MATLAB "conv"command valid/legal for both causal and non causal signals?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

Can we use the built in MATLAB command "conv" for both scenarios of  causal and non causal signals/sequences?
MATLAB help for "conv"command at below Link doesn't explicitly specifies anything about usage with causal signal

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html

Comment: A causal signal? A system can be causal, a signal is just a signal. `conv` works for any linear time-invariant system. That is the definition of convolution. See at the bottom of the page you linked, where the operation of `conv` is described mathematically.

Comment: @engr If by "causal signal" you mean one that is nonzero for negative time, yes, you can do that. `conv` doesn't care where you place the time origin. You just have to keep track of the time indices of the result